# prevent restart server variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to disable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` value of `sql-mode` permanently even restart the MySQL server. following things I have tried to do but which are not working. that set to the default value when restarting the MySQL.

```
setting value on my.ini


sql-mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: Beware, even when you get this disabled, if you then move the database to a server where you cannot (not allowed) to make this amendment your site will not work

Comment: is there any solution to set the sql-mode permanently, that is what I wanted

Comment: Note, it is only MySQL that made the **error** of allowing GROUP BY queries of the form you want to run, the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY parameter is supposed to set things straight and bring MySQL back ___from the dark side___

Comment: the system works perfectly without having `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ` variable in `sql-mode`, the problem I am facing is whenever I restart the server it is needed to set the `sql-mode` that is what I am looking to prevent the variable from setting it up automatically

Comment: Ok so start by telling us the OS you are using.

Comment: windows 10 with mysql 8

Comment: WAMPServer/XAMPP/Some other or did you install it all yourself

Comment: i have installed with xampp server

Comment: XAMPP comes with mariaDB I believe, are you sure you are using MySQL??

Comment: yes this is the version i am using `mysql  Ver 8.0.26 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

Comment: Check the file `mysql_start.bat` No sure where but in the XAMPP file structure somewhere. See if it is using another `my.ini` or has preset parameters on the start of mysql

Comment: my.ini file location is `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` there is no parameter named `preset'

Comment: XAMPP runs a batch file (named as above) to start MySQL when you click the button on the User Interface. It is possible it either has parameters set on the START of the service or it is using a different path to the `my.ini` Just have a look for that file and check

Comment: what should I have to do? Is this the file are you saying `mysqld_multi.pl`

Comment: Well what does it say inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET PERSIST sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Persisted settings are permanent. They apply across server restarts. Persisted settings can be made from local clients or clients who connect from a remote host. This provides the convenience of remotely configuring multiple MySQL servers from a central client host. [MYSQL OFFICIAL LINK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/persisted-system-variables.html)